# Remove a "group by" statement from QueryBuildDataSource at runtime

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I need to remove a group by statement from a QueybuildDataSource object. 
Is there any method to do this? (The opposite of addGroupByField).

Comment: Finally solved making the reverse procedure with removing all group by from the datasource and adding them with a addGroupByField at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Artem, I don't think you can do it from the QBDS level.  I think you need to do it from query().clearGroupBy();

@ian_scho, users under 100 reputation can't answer their own questions for 4-8 hours after posting...that's probably why he didn't post as an answer.

Comment: Ah ok Alex.  I'd better vote up your answer to give you more credos/reputation :)
Thx.

Comment: I appreciate it ian_scho.  Makes it easier to post on these forums haha.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?...

```
QueryBuildDataSource qbds = ????;
QueryBuildFieldList qbdsFL;
;
qbdsFL = qbds.fields();
qbdsFL.clearFieldList();
```

You can then add fields to be grouped programmatically.  Mimmicking a [Select Distinct clause](http://axandhellisfunafterall.blogspot.com/2011/10/select-distinct-fieldid-from-tableid.html) for example.

Comment: This removes the select fields from the query but not a group by.

Comment: Solved making the reverse procedure with removing all group by from the datasource and adding them with a addGroupByField at runtime.

Comment: Then put your comment as an answer to your own question, Artem :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, x++ does not have any method to remove one field from group by but by some tricks we can do that. I have written a method for removing group by field:

```
public void removeGroupByField(FieldID _fieldId, TableId _tableId, Query _query)
    {
        int i = 1;
        QueryGroupByField       qgbf;
        QueryBuildDataSource    qbdsOld, qbdsNew;
        Query                   newQuery;

        qbdsOld             = _query.dataSourceTable(_tableId);

        newQuery            = new Query(_query);    
        qbdsNew             = newQuery.dataSourceTable(_tableId);

        newQuery.clearGroupBy();

        for(i = 1 ; i<= _query.groupByFieldCount(); i++)
        {
            qgbf    = _query.groupByField(i, qbdsOld);
            
            if(qgbf.fieldID() != _fieldId)
            {
                qbdsNew.addGroupByField(qgbf.fieldID());
            }
        }

        _query  = newQuery;
    }
```

And for better performance u can change this method to input container of field Id which u want to remove from group by.